# Overwriting events hash for inherited Backbone.js View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone View for a general element that specific elements will be inheriting from.  I have event handling logic that needs to be applied to all elements, and event handling logic that is specific to child-type elements.  I'm having trouble because a child View has its own callback for an event that is also handled by the parent View, and so when I try to use the events hash in both, either the child or parent callback is never called.  Let me illustrate with some code:

```
var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "mouseup": "upHandler",
    "mousedown": "downHandler",
    "mousemove": "moveHandler"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    // add events from child
    if (this.events)
      this.events = _.defaults(this.events, ElementView.prototype.events);

    this.delegateEvents(this.events);
  }
});

var StrokeView = ElementView.extend({
  events: {
    "mousemove": "strokeMoveHandler"
  }
});
```

How would I solve this in an extensible way, especially if I will later have another level of inheritance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to use "namespaces" for events:

```
var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "mouseup.element": "upHandler",
    "mousedown.element": "downHandler",
    "mousemove.element": "moveHandler"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    // add events from child
    if (this.events)
      this.events = _.defaults(this.events, ElementView.prototype.events);

    this.delegateEvents(this.events);
  }
});

var StrokeView = ElementView.extend({
  events: {
    "mousemove.strokeview": "strokeMoveHandler"
  }
});
```

In fact, this approach is [suggested in Backbone.js documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-bind).

Comment: Good suggestion, although I think your events and namespaces are reversed. Shouldn't it be "mouseup:element"?

Comment: @RobHruska That's not what documentation suggests and also examples "in the wild" point to my suggested usage. Ultimately, it is up to you how you want to structure your event names.

Comment: That's cool. I don't use them very often, and was mainly just going off of other examples I've seen, mainly how jQuery does it: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events.

Comment: Since I'm listening to events that the browser is firing, I'm not naming the events, so if I try namespacing them the handler is not being called.  However, when I switched the names to be in the form @RobHruska suggested (except with a `.` instead of a `:`), i.e. `mousemove.stroke`, it worked.

Comment: @troyastorino I use backbone events mostly for custom events, so I wasn't aware of that. Useful to know.

Answer (score 4):

I've done something similiar by taking advantage of JavaScript's faux-`super` as mentioned in the [Backbone.js documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend) and the initialization function

```
var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "mouseup": "upHandler",
    "mousedown": "downHandler",
    "mousemove": "moveHandler"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.delegateEvents();
  }
});

var StrokeView = ElementView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.events = _.extend({}, this.events, {
      "mousemove": "strokeMoveHandler"
    });

    // Call the parent's initialization function
    ElementView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
  }
});

var SubStrokeView = StrokeView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.events = _.extend({}, this.events, {
      "click": "subStrokeClickHandler",
      "mouseup": "subStrokeMouseupHandler"
    });

    // Call the parent's initialization function
    StrokeView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
  }
});

var c = new SubStrokeView();
console.log(c.events);

// Should be something like
// click: "subStrokeClickHandler"
// mousedown: "downHandler"
// mousemove: "strokeMoveHandler"
// mouseup: "subStrokeMouseupHandler"
```

The magic happens by setting the events within the `initialize` function. If you have multiple `events` attributes in your prototypes, JavaScript will only see the one set most recently due to how prototyping works.

Instead, by doing it this way, each view sets its own `this.events`, then calls its parent's `initialize` function which in turn extends `this.events` with its events, and so on.

You do need to set `this.events` in this specific way:

```
this.events = _.extend({}, this.events, ...new events...);
```

instead of

```
_.extend(this.events, ...new events...);
```

Doing it the second way will munge the events object within the parent's (`ElementView`) prototype. The first way ensures each model gets its own copy.

Comment: I do like this solution, but unfortunately it doesn't deal with the issue that I want both moveHandler and strokeMoveHandler to be called on mouse move events.

Comment: @troyastorino: The proper way to handle that use case is to call the parent method from within your child method.  For example:
`strokeMoveHandler: function() { ElementView.prototype.moveHandler.call(this); // do strokeMoveHandler  stuff }`